# how to run multiple instances of apache on ubuntu amazon ec2 instance

Tags: apache, svn, amazon-ec2

I have already installed subversion on port 80 in apache now inorder to develop web user interface for sub version i need php on same machine i.e is in amazon ec2 instance for this i have to run multiple apache instance port 80 for subversion and another for php how to configure can any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple instances of apache. The easiest way to accomplish this is to enable named virtual hosts. To do this edit /etc/init.d/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (or wherever this file is located on your distro) and add this line to the bottom

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

And then for each site you can either add to the main httpd.conf (not recommended) or you can include individual conf files. To include files you add this line

```
Include [path to site config files]/*.conf
```

And then for each site in a config file you can do something like this (note any options work)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot [path to the document root]
    ServerName [the domain]
    ServerAlias [any alias]
     <Directory "[path to the document root]">
        FileETag None
        Options FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride None  
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all  
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't have domain names for it you can put whatever you like in there, and then just edit your hosts file to look for the ec2 IP when you go to that "domain". You can also add any apache options you want to the virtual site.

Hope this helps.